# How to hide widget from UI without taking up any space in GridView

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I need to hide a widget in a GridView. I searched and tried many ways to hide this widget but it still have space. so this is what I used to solve it

1- I used Visibility

2- I used Offset

3- I used If case but the widget still have place in GridView and ListView ,
I need it to be removed and don't take any space in my Ui.
I give it red color to show .

```
GridView.builder(
                          dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 4
                          ),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            var data = val[index];
                            bool visible = data['isView'] && data['url'] != '';
                            
                            return !visible?Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Container(
                                  color:Colors.red),
                            ): Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    color: data['IsDirectOn']
                                        ? mCD
                                        : Colors.white,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: mCL,
                                          offset: Offset(3, 3),
                                          blurRadius: 3,
                                          spreadRadius: -3),
                                    ]),
                                child: Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: SocialBox(
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        width: width,
                                        height: height,
                                        image: data['image'],
                                        category: data['label']),
                                  ),
                                ),

                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        );
```

Comment: Rather than hiding the item, filter your item list such that "hidden" items are not in the list

Comment: thank you for reply . The data comes from Firebase, and I don't know how to remove index  from Firebase list

Comment: Store your data from Firebase in the form of `List`. Then remove the elements based on your condition `data['isView'] && data['url'] != ''` and pass this updated list to the `GridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data comes from Firebase, and I don't know how to remove index from Firebase list

After getting data from Firebase, you can filter it with your conditions.

```
  _DataList = AllDataList.where((i) => i['isView'] && i['url'] != '').toList();
```